# How can i access a com object created in one function to other function in same class in C#

Tags: c#

Here is my code for getting for connecting my application to the RTD server

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NESTClientLib;

namespace NestToAmi
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static dynamic AmibrokerObj { get; set; }
        public static IScripRTD NestRTDObj { get; set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             int TopicId = 0;
             object[] SymbolList = new object[2];

             TopicId = 1;
             SymbolList[0] = "nse_cm|ITI-EQ";
             SymbolList[1] = "LTP";

             NestRTDObj.ConnectData(TopicId, SymbolList, true);

        }

        public void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                 IScripRTD NestRTDObj = new ScripRTD();      // COM object RTD server
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Nest Trader Interface Error. Check Nest Trader Is Opened or Not \r\n" + ex);
            }
         }
      }
}
```

I wanted to access NestRTDObj (COM object) created in button4_Click to the button1_Click. Please help me in this case.
I tried to access this object as public variable but am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In button 4 handler you declare it as a local variable instead of using the class level field. Remove the type name to fix it.

```
NestRTDObj = new ScripRTD();
```